# Combining Same databse from two different server to third server in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have database **X** which have different data on two different servers and I want to combine the data from both the servers to the new server in **Marklogic** .

Comment: It's unclear if the other databases are also on MarkLogic, or from a different platform. MarkLogic uses clusters, that are comprised of individual servers.  Do you have data on 2 clusters that you want to combine into 1, or is it 1 cluster of 2 servers that you want to combine into one?  Try to add as much detail as possible when asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Super Database and a Super Cluster is what you are asking about

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/superDB

> MarkLogic Server allows you to group multiple databases into a super-database in order to allow a single query to be done across multiple databases. Databases contained in a super-database are called sub-databases. Sub-databases can be distributed on different storage tiers and on different clusters (collectively called super-clusters). A sub-database can be either active (online) or archive (offline), as specified by the kind element.
> [image]